# Can a lightning web component know the difference between console and standard view?

Tags: lightning-web-components, console

I created a LWC which displays a link to an object... and I want that link to "open in a new window" (target "_blank") if the user is viewing it via standard navigation view (non-console).  And, if the user is viewing the LWC within Service Console, then it should utilize standard open (NavigationMixin.Navigate) to open in the current window (which will default to opening a new tab within Console).

I can't seem to find a way for the LWC to be aware of it's context - whether or not it is being displayed in Console.  Is this possible?

(I can provide the LWC; however, I don't think the details of it are relevant to the question, but if it helps someone answer the question I can.)

Answer (score 1):

At the current time, LWC are not supported in the Console. You'd need to put a LWC inside an Aura Component Wrapper in order to use one within the Console. See the [LWC Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_experiences) for more on this.

> Lightning Web Components doesn’t currently support these Salesforce experiences and tools. To use a Lightning web component with these experiences and tools, wrap the component in an Aura component.
>
> - Lightning Out
> - Lightning Components for Visualforce
> - Standalone Apps
> - Salesforce Console (Navigation Item API, Workspace API, UtilityBar API)
> - Utility Bars
> - URL Addressable Tabs
> - Flows
> - Snap-ins Chat
> - Lightning for Gmail, Outlook Integration
> - EMP API, Conversation Toolkit API, Omni Toolkit API, Quick Action API
> - Standard Action Overrides, Custom Actions, Global Actions, List View Actions, Related List View Actions
> - Chatter Extensions

To do what you're asking, you'd also need to implement the [Lightning Console JavaScript API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_js_getting_started.htm) in your component. If you've not migrated to the Lightning Console, I wouldn't expect the toolkit for the classic console to work with LWC's.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that Lightning Web Components don't have access to some of the objects we could access with the Aura Framework. Lightning Locker blocks them. The current ["Migrate Global Value Providers" page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/migrate_gvps) doesn't have on its list an item to show what is the current user's Theme.

The `@salesforce` [module](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/reference_salesforce_modules) does provide a single information now, which is the user's Id. Maybe in future releases Salesforce adds more information, like the theme and other user attributes, like `$User` global variable in Visualforce pages.

---

The workaround **for now** would be to do a server-side call and get the information from the `UserInfo` class. Use the [`.getUiThemeDisplayed()` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#!) to get the current theme displayed to the user.

The documentation lists some themes, and two of them should be of interest to you:

- Theme4d—Modern “Lightning Experience” Salesforce theme
- Theme4u—Lightning Console theme

Theme `Theme4d` should be the "standard" one, while `Theme4u` is the console. Store this string in your component and build your navigation methods accordingly.