# Theme4u Console not getting returned by Quick Action

Tags: lightning, console, workspaceapi

I am trying to determine whether the user is in Lightning Console when they select a Quick Action (Lightning Component) but it comes back as regular Lightning UI no matter if the user is on a Console layout or not. I'm using same technique described here: [Can a lightning web component know the difference between console and standard view?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263483/can-a-lightning-web-component-know-the-difference-between-console-and-standard-v/263713?r=SearchResults)

Note, unlike OP, my user is not in Service Console.

Comment: Can you add the minimla required code please to see what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [isConsoleNavigation()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation) for getting this information.

> isConsoleNavigation()
>
> Returns a Promise. Success resolves to true if console navigation is
>   present, false otherwise. The Promise will be rejected on error.

Sample:

cmp:

```
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
<lightning:button label="Is Console?" onclick="{! c.checkIfConsole }" />
```

JS:

```
checkIfConsole: function (component, event, helper) {
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.isConsoleNavigation()
    .then(function(infos){
        console.log("is Console? => ", JSON.stringify(infos));
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log("ERROR => ", err));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed